# Assigning {pointer to function with C linkage} to {pointer to function with C++ linkage} and vice versa

Tags: c++, function-pointers, extern, linkage

Is this code legal?

```
extern "C" typedef void (ft_blah_c)();
/*extern "C++"*/ typedef void (ft_blah_cpp)();

extern "C" void fn_blah_c() {}
/*extern "C++"*/ void fn_blah_cpp() {}

ft_blah_c *g_Blah_c = fn_blah_cpp; // <--- ?
ft_blah_cpp *g_Blah_cpp = fn_blah_c; // <--- ?
```

I have real code with similiar assigments, it compiles and executes without any problems (MSVC 2010).

Comment: @WhozCraig seems like you are confused storage with linkage.

Comment: Does C and C++ use the same calling convention for `void fn()`? I don't think either standard say anything about that. The platform specific documentation might.

Comment: @WhozCraig: `7.5 Linkage specifications` States that two types with different language linkage are **are distinct types even if they are otherwise identical**. The compiler should reject the assignment on this basis alone. But it does not.

Comment: @LokiAstari Thank you! I never knew this, and have no doubt exploited compilers in the past that skip it. Must have been quite lucky. Thank you very much for the info.

Answer (score 4):

In general that should not work. The problem is that when you call `fn_blah_c` or `fn_blah_cpp`directly the compiler *knows* the function and the calling conventions to use, but if you store those in a function pointer the compiler only sees that pointer and can only use the type of the function pointer to determine how to pass the arguments and return types.

If the calling convention for C and C++ are the same in your environment then it can work (and that is probably why your compiler is allowing it), but that is not the case in general and the assignment should fail.

Comment: Though the linkage is part of the type. I have found that most compilers do not check and will allow the assignment even if they are not compatible and blow up very nicely when a call is made. The other thing here that may be helping is that no parameters are passed and no return value is used so this is the simplist call to make and just requires that both conventions use the same location for the return address of the instruction pointer (probably true everywhere).

Comment: So i'm curious, since I've not seen the standard on calling conventions (are they even in there??) is the current default convention used unless it is specified on the function decl? And also, i've purposed had to declare function pointers that *must* specify a non-default calling convention when being assigned function addresses that are themselves using a specific non-default convention. Generally will the compiler catch such an assignment if the pointer is *not* declared with the same convention preface? MSVC, for example, allows convention attachment to function pointers.

Comment: @LokiAstari in my real code I have funtions with parameters and return types (actually, I have big funtion table).

Comment: @ShadowsInRain: As David said. It will work if the compiler uses the same calling convention for both languages. But there is no grantees about that in the standard and you should not rely on it.

Comment: @WhozCraig: The standard deliberately does not specify anything about calling conventions (this is an implementation detail). You need to consult your compiler documentation which will probably defer you to the platform documentation (of course MS owns both these layers).

Comment: @LokiAstari not even going to bother if they're distinct types due to different linkages as you've pointed out. I just read 7.5 of the C++11 spec and its there plain as day in paragraph 1. thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: it's not guaranteed by the standard but AFAIK the only compiler that warns about is Solaris CC. IIRC. and the warning can be turned off.

Comment: so, it's one of the *de facto* standards of C++. another is that a struct with a single byte member is one byte size. there's probably a gazillion lines of code around that relies on those *de facto* standards.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not legal; conversion between function types cannot be implicit.

It is legal to explicitly cast between function types:

```
ft_blah_c *g_Blah_c = reinterpret_cast<ft_blah_c>(fn_blah_cpp);
ft_blah_cpp *g_Blah_cpp = reinterpret_cast<ft_blah_cpp>(fn_blah_c);
```

However actually calling a function through a function pointer of a different type is undefined behavior. You must convert back to the original type before calling the function.

The underlying reason for this, outside the scope of the standard, is that the machine instructions for calling a function can differ based on the function's language linkage. This is referred to as ['calling conventions'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) and involve many details such as argument and return value passing conventions, function prologue and epilogue, etc.

For example a function with C language linkage may expect to find its arguments on the stack while a function with C++ language linkage may expect arguments to be passed in registers. If calling code doesn't know the correct linkage it will place the argument data one place and the function will look in the other and only read garbage, thus failing to operate correctly.

Comment: Are you aware of any compilers that exercise this ability to use a different calling convention?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can make VC++ use different calling conventions for C and C++ functions.

Comment: Checking [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage#Notes): *The only modern compiler that differentiates function types with "C" and "C++" language linkages is Oracle Studio, others do not permit overloads that are only different in language linkage, including the overload sets required by the C++ standard (std::qsort, std::bsearch, std::signal, std::atexit, and std::at_quick_exit)*